# jquery parent selector issue in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, parent

Jquery parent selector is not working in IE8..It's working with other browsers(chrome,firefox,opera,safari)

I'm using it like :

```
comment = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".commentWrapper");
```

Any idea?

--Edit--

Sorry for the misleading
Turns out error is next line ;

```
postId = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name = "postId"]').val();
```

And IE Developer tool shows this error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

But if i declare postId like var postId, it's working fine.. But I didnt understand what is the problem actually?

Comment: Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of multiple `parent()` calls..? But I've got no idea what's making it fail in IE, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: What does $(this).parent(), $(this).parent().parent(), $(this).parent().parent().parent() matches? When does it become different in IE8?

Comment: If you want help, you will HAVE to show us the HTML that you're trying this on.

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is not the parent() selector. I was  looking wrong places for the error. Thank you for help

Comment: You've had multiple comments asking for your HTML.  If you want help, that's what we need.

Answer (score 1):

if you know parent selector, better to use parents('selector').
http://api.jquery.com/parents/